# 3-D plot of $0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 1,0\leq z\leq 1$

Tags: graphing-functions

I can't figure this out :
When we plot the inequalities  $0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 1,0\leq z\leq 1$ graphically what do we obtain ?
Kindly help..

Comment: It is a very special kind of "cubic" equation ;)

Comment: Is the cube $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

A cube ! With one vertex at $(0,0,0)$ and the "opposite" one in $(1,1,1)$.